# r log and log in excel not matching

Tags: r, excel, logging

I am estimating the log of few numbers

```
raw <- c(0.9709, 11.0132, 1.2401, 0.2686, 0.4751)

log(raw)

-0.0295, 2.399, 0.2151, -1.314, -0.744
```

When I use the log function in excel I cannot reproduce these log transformed numbers (-0.0295, 2.399, 0.2151, -1.314, -0.744). What is the r equivalent log function in excel ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `=LOG()` function in excel is the same as `log10()` in R, and, as Jeremy Kahan says below, the `log()` function in R is the same as `=LN()` in excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need ln, not log in excel.